# Can we send pair a template argumrent another pair

Tags: c++, std-pair

Can we use pair as an argument for another pair in C++.

Here is a test program to do that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::pair<int,int> m;
    m=std::make_pair(1,3);
    int r = 3;
    int *q = &r;
    int **p =&q;
    int **t = p;
    std::pair<int**,<std::pair<int,int> > > i(p,m);
    std::cout<<i[t];

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error, I am getting.

```
Test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Test.cpp:12:45: error: template argument 2 is invalid
  std::pair<int**,<std::pair<int,int>>> i(p,m);
                                             ^
```

If I changed the format of declaration and wrote the program in the following way,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::pair<int,int> m;
    m=std::make_pair(1,3);
    int r = 3;
    int *q = &r;
    int **p =&q;
    int **t = p;
    std::pair<
                int**,
                <
                    std::pair<
                                int,
                                int
                                >
                            >
                        > i(p,m);
    std::cout<<i[t];

    return 0;
}
```

There is an additional error.

```
Test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Test.cpp:20:7: error: template argument 2 is invalid
       > i(p,m);
       ^
Test.cpp:20:14: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
       > i(p,m);
```

What might be the issue and how to solve it?

---

On a side note, I did a program and compiled it in an very old Dev-c++ compiler on a windows 7 machine which used a code similar to the above and it ran perfectly fine. It was a lab program in my college which had only that compiler.

The above code, I ran on both windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 using GNU g++ 5.4.0

Ideone: [Link to the actual program for reference](http://ideone.com/YA2W69)

You might also have a look at the actual error, I faced in the above link.

Comment: After seeing the answers, I see the syntactic blunder I made. I don't remember how much I changed the code. There seems to be lots of other errors in the code linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
std::pair<int**,<std::pair<int,int> > > i(p,m);
```

Just remove the extra `<>`:

```
std::pair<int**, std::pair<int,int > > i(p,m);
```

Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to do in the `cout` part, but `pair` doesn't have a `[]` operator. You can access the elements with `first` and `second`:

```
i.first
i.second
i.second.first
i.second.second
```

You may also be interested in `std::tuple` if you don't want to nest one pair into another:

```
std::tuple<int**, int, int> i;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code.

1. You have a superfluous pair of angle brackets in your template instantiation.
2. The `cout` parameter makes no sense

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::pair<int,int> m;
    m=std::make_pair(1,3);
    int r = 3;
    int *q = &r;
    int **p =&q;
    int **t = p;
    std::pair<
                int**,
                // < Omit this
                    std::pair<
                                int,
                                int
                                >
                            // > also this
                        > i(p,m);
    // std::cout<<i.[t]; indexing with a pointer value doesn't make sense
    // i. for a pair doesn't make sense, specify either first or second
    std::cout<<i.first[0]; // <<<< Did you mean something like this?

    return 0;
}
```

[Check the compiling version live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de4052a37d02574e)